# Generating PDFs directly to path on s3fs (mounted Amazon S3 bucket)

Tags: amazon-s3, fuse, pdflib, s3fs

Has anyone used the s3fs utility for Amazon S3?

I have some scripts that generate large PDF documents on-the-fly, most will be in the 10+ MB range, but some will be perhaps 2 GB.

Is there any danger to generating large files such as this directly to an s3fs drive?

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received confirmation that although it may work most of the time, **no** it is not completely safe.

Answer (score 1):

I use S3FS in a production environment in combination with PureFTPd to save large file uploads. We have not run into issues as of yet.

I would however recommend using daemontools/runit or some other supervision type of process.